# How to interpret testing loss? When exactly can we say a model is overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, keras

So, I used the Keras sequential model in Python. I understand that, well training and testing accuracy are self explanatory, validation accuracy is a measure on how well it predicts for new data,

And training loss << validation loss --> overfits

Training loss >> validation loss --> underfits

About equal --> fits well

So for overfitting, how much is <<? Is a training loss of 0.24 versus 1.00 validation loss overfitting or does it fit well?
And I have no clue how to interpret testing loss?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I see it overfits when the validation loss (if loss is your metric) keeps increasing while the training loss continues to decrease.

Answering your question, the amount of difference doesn't really matter in 1 particular epoch (because this might be affected by other factors, e.g. amount of training vs validation split), what's important is if the difference gets larger over time.

To combat, use some helpful callbacks to monitor if a metric doesn't improve after a certain amount of epochs. EarlyStopping callback uses this and stops the training, or ReduceLROnPlateau callback reduces your learning rate so hopefully you don't overshoot a local/global optima